# how to use "selection" event listener on autoComplete javascript library

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I've been spending the last few days trying to figure out how to use [TarekRaafat's autoComplete.js](https://github.com/TarekRaafat/autoComplete.js) on one of my input box. my current problem is, when I click one of the options, nothing happens. here's what I tried: https://jsfiddle.net/vjyLagh8/14/

the `console.log` in 'selection' event are not called

```
  autoCompleteJS.input.addEventListener("selection", function (e) {
    console.log('selection detail'); // ==> this doesn't appear in dev tools
    // ...
  });
```

I'm doing it exactly like in the [codepen example](https://codepen.io/dapidmini/pen/QWaBYjP?editors=1111) but why is my code not working? what am I doing wrong?

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit late but the event is called `"select"`, not `"selection"`

```
autoCompleteJS.input.addEventListener("select", function (e) {
    console.log('This works');
});
```